# Prototyping with SMD components?

Tags: prototyping, dip

In response to the answers here: [How much longer should we expect DIP (or DIL) Packaging to be around?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/21632/6366)

If DIPs are phasing out, how would one proto their boards quickly and cheaply? Does this mean we have to all start learning to build surface mount boards? Is there something I'm missing because that sounds like a lot of work for simple proof of concepts...

Comment: related: [How to use multiple terminal surface mount chips in amateur project?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/8000/how-to-use-multiple-terminal-surface-mount-chips-in-amateur-project)

Comment: See my answer [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21608/solderable-solderless-breadboards) for some SMD prototyping stuff

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Several vendors offer tiny PCBs that adapt SMT devices to match DIP footprints.

Typically, the SMT part and a set of pins must be soldered to the PCB.

A representative vendor can be found [here](http://www.futurlec.com/SMD_Adapters.shtml).

Comment: Any representative vendors for the UK, or search terms that I might employ in order to discover such vendors?